# How to convert a C function inputs with char** argv to python?

Tags: python, c

I want to convert a C code with the function below to python code, but I get errors.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int year, month, day;
    int jul;
    day = atoi(argv[1]);
    month = atoi(argv[2]);
    year = atoi(argv[3]);
...
```

when I write this python code for it, I get errors:

```
def main(argc, **argv):

day = int(argv[1])
month = int(argv[2])
year = int(argv[3])
```

Comment: Is that Python code properly formatted? And when asking questions about errors, first of all please show us a [mcve] which replicates the problem, and always include the errors. So please create a [mcve] to show us, and then copy-paste (as text) the *complete* and *full* error output from the shown example.

Comment: `**argv` assumes a mapping like a `dict`. If `argv` is a `str`, you might want either `*argv` or just `argv`. We will need to see *exactly* how you are calling `main` in order to help

Comment: Or perhaps all you need is some [good Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/)?

Comment: well you have no code block inside main, and you haven't defined `argv`

Comment: Do you know what the `char**` in `C` means?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from sys import argv

def main():
    day = int(argv[1])
    month = int(argv[2])
    year = int(argv[3])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For future reference, you should post the errors that you get, rather than just saying that you "get errors."

Comment: It's not common style to `from sys import argv`... it's far more traditional to `import sys` and then use `sys.argv`...

Comment: @JonClements although it's not really bad in this case is it- not really namespace polluting or shadowing anything?

Comment: @JonClements do you have a source or a justification other than "common" and "traditional"? The only component of the `sys` module I use in this code is `argv`, so I don't see what's wrong with importing it only.

Comment: @Chris_Rands nope... but everyone will immediately know that `sys.argv` is going to be the command line arguments without having to check... `argv` could just be any arbitrary thing... or maybe even a typo of `args` or `*args`...

Comment: Well, let's put it another way, in 15 years of Python, this is the first time I've ever seen `from sys import argv` used anywhere (it's not in the standard library, I've never seen it used in myriads of projects I've been involved with or on github etc...)... as it's such short code it's easy to spot it, but if I'm a page or two down, seeing `argv` I'd have to check what it might be, seeing `sys.argv` - I don't exactly what it is - or supposed to be.

Comment: @JonClements Well i agree `sys.argv` is more common but `from sys import argv` still has >100K hits on github https://github.com/search?q=%22from+sys+import+argv%22&type=Code

Comment: @Chris_Rands Okay... given the evidence, I'll have to concede one of my points then... however, since the OP is obviously new though, it's probably best to suggest the more established and documented approach used within Python itself?

Comment: @JonClements it may be that the pattern I've used above is uncommon because codebases with complex arguments tend to use a library that takes care of agument parsing, such as `argparse`. Just looking through the GitHub link, many uses of "`from sys import argv`" tend to be beginners learning to program, so I feel that its use is appropriate here.

Comment: @jarhill0 indeed... I tend to only use `sys.argv` for quick and dirty (and most likely disposable scripts).

Comment: Well, when people are learning, I tend to find it's best to introduce the more common and easily interpreted practices rather than short hands... but anyway... 6 of one and half dozen of the other and all that :)